# ValueError: Unknown engine: openpyxl when trying to load Excel file to a dataframe on a Jupyternotebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I'm getting this error: 'ValueError: Unknown engine: openpyxl' when I try to run this on a Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\XXX\YYY.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
```

Already installed openpyxl with pip:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

'Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.'

Already restarted the Kernel but the error persists.

Can someone help me here?

Thank you.

Comment: Update Pandas .... not reproduced error in pandas 1.4.1 version

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude engine='openpyxl', and retry.
Looks little bit weird, but it works for me.

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\XXX\YYY.xlsx")